# C# How to fill datagridview with a property of an object that is stored inside an object of a List<object>

Tags: c#, list, object, datagridview, populate

```
  public abstract class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Manager:Person
    {
        public int Trophies { get; set; }

    }
    public class Team
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Manager manager { get; set; }
        public Team() { }

        public Team(string _name,Manager _mananger)
        {
            Name = _name;
            manager = _mananger;
        Lists.ListOfTeams.Add(this);
        }
    }
    public static class Lists {
        public static List<Team> ListOfTeams = new List<Team>();
    }


My code : 
datagridTeams.Datasource = Lists.ListOfTeams;
```

I want to populate a datagrid with the List of teams , also their managers name but I can not achieve that , it just gives me the result ListOfTeams.Manger;
Can anyone help me how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a public get only property that gets the manager's name (ManagerName) in the Team class. This will help you achieve what you are looking for.

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName => Manager.Name;
    public Manager manager { get; set; }
    public Team() { }

    public Team(string _name,Manager _mananger)
    {
        Name = _name;
        manager = _mananger;
    Lists.ListOfTeams.Add(this);
    }
}
```